# Как сделать переход на прошлую страницу после авторизации?

Tags: python, flask

Авторизация на сайте происходит через апи вк.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.vk_login') }}">Войти через ВК</a>
```

Переадресация на получение кода

```
@auth.route('/redirect_to_vk_login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def vk_login():
    vk_info = get_vk()
    url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=%s&display=popup&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&v=5".73' % (
        vk_info['id'], vk_info['url'])
    return redirect(url)
```

Функция получения токена и переадресация:

```
@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    if request.args.get('code') is None:
        return abort(501)

    ... получаю токен


    ... записываю в бд

    # Get information about the user
    data = {'user_id': response.json().get('user_id')}
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get'
    response = requests.post(url, params=data).json()['response'][0]

    information_about_user = {
        'logged_in': True,
        'user_id': response['uid'],
        'first_name': response['first_name'],
        'last_name': response['last_name']
    }
    session.update(information_about_user)

    # Как сделать переход на прошлую страницу после авторизации? 
    return redirect(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

- В функции vk_login записать в сессию исходный адрес:

  `session['previous_url'] = request.referrer`
- В функции login переадресовать на этот адрес:

  `redirect(session['previous_url'])`

Comment: Спасибо большое!